# Should you git branch if the intention is to change the master branch drastically

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I am taking over the ownership of a git repository which only has a master branch. I intend in  branching a develop branch and drastically changing the repo structure.

If I do this and then merge back into the master. Should I be using the 'ours' merge strategy to just forcibly use my branch in merge conflicts instead of master.

Or would there be another preferred approach? Quite often in the past if I try to merge a drastically changed branch with the master branch in order to push to live, conflicts inevitable arise.

Comment: What about creating a new branch off of `master` and renaming them? Agree w/ @TimWolla that conflicts should not occur unless there are content changes in two separate branches and you attempt to merge them. You can switch between branches w/o merging as long as you don't have unstaged changes.

Answer (score 3):

Conflicts only arise if the base branch was changed in the meantime as well.

Depending on what changes you would expect you should *not* use `ours` as it *may* throw away valuable changes. If you don't care: Go for it.

The best way would be ensuring that no or only few, easily mergable, commits happens in `master` in the meantime.